# Slow Informix COUNT/GROUP BY query, even with appropriate index

Tags: sql, database, performance, optimization, informix

I have a very simple query that is running slow in Informix 11 even though an appropriate index exists and it is being used:

```
select COUNTRY, COUNT(*) from EVENTS group by COUNTRY
```

Is there any reason why it should run slow? I have experience in similar queries with SQL Server and they execute immediately if an appropriate index exists.

More information:

- The query takes around 15 seconds for 500.000 records in EVENTS table (which worries me because this table will have millions of records and I have seen that the execution time is increasing rapidly).
- EVENTS table has an index by COUNTRY. By using EXPLAIN directive I have checked that this index is being used.
- EVENTS table has many columns (around 70).
- "country" column is varchar(32).
- There are 25 different values for "country".
- A table scan is done by Informix:

```
1) informix.EVENTS: INDEX PATH
```

`(1) Index Name: informix.country_ix
    Index Keys: COUNTRY   (Serial, fragments: ALL)


Query statistics:
-----------------

Table map :
----------------------------
Internal name     Table name
----------------------------
t1                EVENTS

type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
-------------------------------------------------------------------
scan     t1     501906     39285     501906     00:14.88   29390   

type     rows_prod  est_rows  rows_cons  time       est_cost
------------------------------------------------------------
group    25         4         501906     00:15.58   79761`

Comment: Is it version 11.10, 11.50, or 11.70 that you're using?  Have you run UPDATE STATISTICS at all?  Not running that used to be much more of a problem than it is with the most recent versions (12.10, for example), but it is still worth checking. What platform are you running on?  How big is a row in the events table?

Comment: It still has to read all the index pages in order to count the number of events per COUNTRY.

Comment: My Informix version is 11.70.UC4D running in Linux (Ubuntu). I have updated statistics but it makes no difference. However (as I told Lorenzo below) removing the index (and forcing SEQUENTIAL SCAN), the query is executed much faster, which surprises me. I will try to calculate the row size. As a first approximation, it could be around 1kB per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i did some testing.

TL;DR

- Change the country column type to `CHAR(32)`, rebuild the index and you should have much better performance.

Long Version:

Used informix 12.10FC6DE on linux centos 7 (VM created in virtualbox). Page size used for the dbspace was 2048 Bytes, buffer pool is 50000 pages.

Created a table (tst) with with a row size around 425 Bytes (average 4 rows per page), with several columns. Of those columns, one is `country VARCHAR(32)` and other is `static_country CHAR(32)`.
Populated the table with 499999 rows, with the columns `country` and `static_country` evenly distributed for 25 country names.

Created 2 indexes, one on column `country` (idx1_tst) and other on column `static_country` (idx2_tst).

The table partition had 125000 data pages used (using oncheck -pT).
The indexes had around 1500 pages used (using oncheck -pT).

**A.** Run the query several times, forcing a SEQUENCIAL SCAN (run times were between 10 and 15 seconds):

```
SELECT --+ FULL (tst)
    country, COUNT(*)
FROM
    tst
GROUP BY
    country

DIRECTIVES FOLLOWED:
FULL ( tst )
DIRECTIVES NOT FOLLOWED:

Estimated Cost: 1415645
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 25
Temporary Files Required For: Group By

  1) mydb.tst: SEQUENTIAL SCAN


Query statistics:
-----------------

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                tst

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     499999     499999    499999     00:12.17   140001

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  rows_cons  time       est_cost
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  group    25         25        499999     00:13.01   1275644
```

**B.** Run the query several times, forcing a INDEX SCAN on the `country` column index, which is of type VARCHAR(32) (run times between 4m30s and 5m):

```
SELECT --+ INDEX (tst idx1_tst)
    country, COUNT(*)
FROM
    tst
GROUP BY
    country

DIRECTIVES FOLLOWED:
INDEX ( tst idx1_tst )
DIRECTIVES NOT FOLLOWED:

Estimated Cost: 3462411
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 25

  1) mydb.tst: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: mydb.idx1_tst
        Index Keys: country   (Serial, fragments: ALL)


Query statistics:
-----------------

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                tst

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     499999     499999    499999     04:49.71   3462411

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  rows_cons  time       est_cost
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  group    25         25        499999     04:50.51   1275644
```

**C.** Run the query several times, forcing a INDEX SCAN on the `static_country` column index, which is of type CHAR(32) (run times between 2 and 3 seconds):

```
SELECT --+ INDEX (tst idx2_tst)
    static_country, COUNT(*)
FROM
    tst
GROUP BY
    static_country

DIRECTIVES FOLLOWED:
INDEX ( tst idx2_tst )
DIRECTIVES NOT FOLLOWED:

Estimated Cost: 16428
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 25

  1) mydb.tst: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: mydb.idx2_tst
        Index Keys: static_country   (Key-Only)  (Serial, fragments: ALL)


Query statistics:
-----------------

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                tst

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     499999     499999    499999     00:02.02   16429

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  rows_cons  time       est_cost
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  group    25         25        499999     00:02.72   1277132
```

Using the SMI table `sysptprof` on the sysmaster database i can see the following counters (using `onstat -z` between runs to reset the counters):

1. In case A (SEQUENCIAL SCAN):

   - table tst partition:

     - `lockreqs          499999`
     - `isreads           125001`
     - `bufreads          500060`
     - `pagreads          117532`
2. In case B (INDEX SCAN on the VARCHAR type column):

   - table tst partition:

     - `lockreqs          499999`
     - `isreads           499990`
     - `bufreads          999997`
     - `pagreads          348585`
   - index idx1_tst partition:

     - `lockreqs          499999`
     - `isreads           500009`
     - `bufreads          506961`
     - `pagreads          2545`
3. In case C (INDEX SCAN on the CHAR type column):

   - index idx2_tst partition:

     - `lockreqs          499999`
     - `isreads           500000`
     - `bufreads          502879`
     - `pagreads          1440`

So, for the SEQUENCIAL SCAN there is only have activity on the table partition, as I expected.

For the INDEX SCAN on the CHAR column there is only activity on the index partition, as I expected (the explain contains the `Key-Only` indication).

For the INDEX SCAN on the VARCHAR colum, there is activity in both the table and index partitions, not what I expected (but as Fernando pointed out, the explain does not contain the `Key-Only` indication).

I cannot explain this behavior from informix. But a colleague pointed me to this entry on the informix performance manual (version 12.10FC6, chapter 10, the query plan, the access plan):

> Important: The optimizer does not choose a key-only scan for a VARCHAR
>   column. If you want to take advantage of key-only scans, use the ALTER
>   TABLE with the MODIFY clause to change the column to a CHAR data type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough investigation and your detailed explanations, Luis. I changed from VARCHAR to CHAR and now the query executes fast (400 ms for 250,000 records, 500 ms for 500,000 and 800 ms for 1,000,000). Now my sqexplain says Key-Only. Replacing COUNT(*) by COUNT(1) makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Things I would try:

- `COUNT(1)` rather than `COUNT(*)` in case the DBMS is stupid
- testing the query and inspecting the execution plan without the index because it might be a source of confusion
- testing what queries the index speeds up and trying different index types

Comment: Thank you for your hints, Lorenzo. Using `COUNT(country)` or `COUNT(1)` makes no difference. However, removing the index (with which Informix changes from INDEX PATH to SEQUENTIAL SCAN) the query is executed much faster (5 seconds instead of 15). I wonder why! I can’t think of any other index (different from the one I have: single column “country”).

Comment: It would be interesting to see the query plan of the other options.
Today I saw this "eefect" on a similar query. It's noticeable that the query plan doesn't mention "key-only" and this matches the answer perfectly and it was verified that the data partition was being accessed.
Using COUNT(1) should get rid of this effect.